# PHP Remove <br> in last line with

Tags: php, scripting

Currently I have this code:

```
<?php
echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex">';
$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/    paper_items.json"),true);
foreach($arr as $item) {

$label = $item['label'];
$cost = $item['cost'];
$id = $item['paper_item_id'];
$member = $item['is_member'];

if ($member == "1") {
$member = "Yes";
}else{
$member = "No";
}

echo  "$label = $id = $member = $cost";
echo ",<br>";
}  
?>
```

What this code does it that it adds a 
 tag after every line. This is the snippet that it happens in:

```
echo  "$label = $id = $member = $cost";
echo ",<br>";
```

What I want is at the last line for the line `echo ",<br>";` to NOT be ran. How do I do this? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<?php
$str = '';
$str .= '<meta name="robots" content="noindex">';
$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/    paper_items.json"),true);
foreach($arr as $item) {

$label = $item['label'];
$cost = $item['cost'];
$id = $item['paper_item_id'];
$member = $item['is_member'];

if ($member == "1") {
$member = "Yes";
}else{
$member = "No";
}

$str .= "$label = $id = $member = $cost";
$str .= ",<br>";
}  

echo substr($str, 0, -5);
?>
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
$result = array();

foreach($arr as $item) {
  ...

  $result[] =  "$label = $id = $member = $cost";
}

echo implode('<br />', $result);
```

Idea is to store all rows in array and join items with BR tag after your loop finished working.

Comment: this is a good solution if the OP always wants to join on <br> (which is true for this example, but not necessarily for other examples in the future). So, for this particular situation this is the best approach (and quite elegant) but in general I think my solution is the more universal one for assembling strings for output and then removing some unwanted trailing token. The biggest shortcoming of this approach is if you wish to style the rows alternately, for example, you're left having to do all sorts of summersaults to make that a reality.

Comment: I never claimed it's the best solution or universal one for all cases, i just responded to this particular case ;)

Comment: I think it's hilarious that when all is said and done the OP selects the answer that is *almost as correct as my answer, even as my answer has a -1 downvote, and yours has 8 upvotes. I guess there's really no accounting for taste! In any event, you are right, for this exact problem, as the upvotes (to which I am party) show, this is the most elegant and easiest way to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

I like [ioseb's explode solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10964445/398242), but here's [another easy way](http://codepad.org/isZDVfNc):

```
foreach($arr as $item) {

    $first = isset($first) && print ",<br>";

    // ...

    echo  "$label = $id = $member = $cost";
}
```

This prints the line break on all but the first iteration - but *before* the text, just make sure `$first` isn't set before running it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing all your items in a string rather than echoing as you go. then you can remove whatever trailing characters you want when you're done before you echo just once at the end with a simple regex like...

```
echo preg_replace('/\<br\/\>$/','', $myTotalOutputString);
```

Answer (score 0):

A small rewrite of your code:

```
<?php
echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex">';
$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paper_items.json"), true);
$outArray = array();
foreach($arr as $item) {
    $label = $item['label'];
    $cost = $item['cost'];
    $id = $item['paper_item_id'];
    $member = ($item['is_member'] == '1') ? "Yes" : "No";
    $outArray[] = "{$label} = {$id} = {$member} = {$cost}";
}  

echo implode(',<br>', $outArray);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Quick one-liner using rtrim:

```
echo rtrim('test <br />', '<br />');
```

But I voted for the implode answer above.